# Screen Flow issue

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-flow

How can i control help text message that are being showing on my screen flow?
i.e. I have added help text on my screen flow header on my one dev org and it is showing on new popup / modal when i click on help [i] icon button

[image]

And on second dev org I have added help text on my screen flow header and I just have to hover mouse on help [i] icon it just diplay it.

[image]

Both dev org have same version of salesforce

I want to able to display help text message when i hover to help [i] icon so it will good user interface on my both dev org.

Please suggest any solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is a bug
2. Kindly raise a case with Salesforce for the same!
3. As said this not an expected behaviour.